# Rails - Handle User roles using pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table of users with enum user_type [Manager, Developer, QA]. Currently, I'm handling sign in using Devise and after login I'm using the following logic to display the appropriate webpage:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    if current_user.manager?
      redirect_to manager_path(current_user.id)
    end
    if current_user.developer?
      redirect_to developer_path(current_user.id)
    end
    if current_user.quality_assurance?
      redirect_to qa_path(current_user.id)
    end
  end
end
```

I want to use pundit gem to handle this. From the documentation, it transpired that this logic will be delegated to policies but I can't figure out how. Can somebody help me in implementing pundit in my project?

This is my users table:
[image: Users]

I have created a user_policy but its mostly empty:

```
class UserPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < Scope
    def resolve
      scope.all
    end
  end
end
```

User model:

[image]

Comment: You're totally confused here. Its not Pundits job to decide where the user gets redirected. Pundits job is to simply authorize if the user is permitted to perform an action or not - your policy methods simply return a boolean and if its false a `Pundit::NotAuthorizedError` will be raised which can rescued in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Pundit to **authorize** a user, as in check if that user should be allowed to visit a controller action. **If the user is not authorized** for a specific action it raises a `Pundit::NotAuthorizedError`

You can check if a user is allowed to perform an action in the pundit policy, in which you have access to **record** (the instance thats passed to authorize) and **user**. So assuming you have a Flat Model, where only the owner can edit the Flat you might do this:

```rb
# flats_policy.rb
def edit?
  record.user == user
end
```

Now lets say you also want to allow admins to edit you might do this

```rb
# flats_policy.rb
def owner_or_admin?
  record.user == user || user.admin # where admin is a boolean
end

def edit?
  owner_or_admin?
end
```

and the controller:

```rb
# flats_controller.rb
def edit
  @flat = Flat.find(params[:id])
  authorize @flat
  # other code here
end
```

Now the **index** action is the odd one out because you would essentially have to call `authorize` on each instance, so the way Pundit handles this is with the Scope:

```rb
# flats_policy.rb
class Scope < Scope
  def resolve
    scope.all
  end
end
```

and a corresponding index action might look like:

```rb
def index
  @flats = policy_scope(Flat) # note that we call the model here
end
```

So lets say a user can only see flats that he/she owns:

```rb
# flats_policy.rb
class Scope < Scope
  def resolve
    scope.where(user: user)
  end
end
```

and if admins can see all flats:

```rb
# flats_policy.rb
class Scope < Scope
  def resolve
    if user.admin
      scope.all
    else
      scope.where(user: user)
    end
  end
end
```

In any case if the user is not allowed to perform an action you can rescue from the error like so:

```rb
# application_controller
rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError, with: :user_not_authorized
def user_not_authorized
  flash[:alert] = "You are not authorized to perform this action."
  redirect_to(root_path)
end
```

I guess you could do some dirty redirecting here, as in send admins to an admins_root_path, users to a default_root_path and so on...

On a final note, since this post is already too long you can check a policy in the view like this:

```
<% if policy(restaurant).edit? %>
  You can see me if you have edit rights
<% end %>
```